# How to share session with multiple web applications

Tags: reactjs, web, session, browser, aem

Our current website is in AEM(CMS) and front-end is in react-js,

so the ask is we have to create a new website in react-js which should be seamless(means that if user switch to new website he should not know that he is redirect to any other site)
so from the point of UI/UX header and footer should be same as the original site create in AEM/React,

so for this we have to read the browser session data in new website site which was set up by the website create in AEM/React.

Please share any working React-JS example code if possible.

Comment: This seems like a very fishy requirement security-wise and it has little to do with React (other than maybe sharing some UI code). To solve this, you'd need a project, not a StackOverflow answer. The UX is the tip of the iceberg. Do those websites share a common domain? How are they implemented? How are sessions currently managed? Do you have single sign-on? Do you have control over one of those sites or both? What is the relationship between the sites? Are they meant to coexist indefinitely? Are you doing a migration? I'd have to do a workshop just to know where to start.

Comment: Do those websites share a common domain? 
Ans: Currently not but if we want then we can.

How are they implemented?
Ans: New project/site will be on React.

How are sessions currently managed?
Ans: being managed in current website

Do you have single sign-on?
Ans: No

Do you have control over one of those sites or both?
Ans: Yes on both

What is the relationship between the sites?
Ans: New site should follow the headless architecture, hence new functionality will be implemented seperately

Are they meant to coexist indefinitely?
Ans yes 

Are you doing a migration?
Ans No